# How do I import a saved VPN configuration in 16.04?

Tags: network-manager, 16.04, vpn

I'm using vpn.ht and it provides a configuration file that you download and import for the network manager. Starting with the 16.04 update (I did a clean install), I can't import a saved configuration for a VPN. It's not even listed as one of the options anymore. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please make sure you have the following packages installed:

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

You can install them on the command line by copying and pasting the following command:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-vpnc
```

When they have finished installing, you may need to log out and log back in, or possibly restart your computer, for the changes to take effect. Network-Manager should then show various vpn options.

Please let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.